# How to get file (video) duration of google drive file programmatically?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

Either using rest API, Google Scripts, Node SDK, whatever works.

I'm seeing this in the docs but that doesn't seem to tell me the duration:

```
function watchFile(fileId, channelId, channelType, channelAddress) {
  var resource = {
    'id': channelId,
    'type': channelType,
    'address': channelAddress
  };
  var request = gapi.client.drive.files.watch({
    'fileId': fileId,
    'resource': resource
  });
  request.execute(function(channel){console.log(channel);});
}
```

I found this link but it doesn't seem to help https://apis-nodejs.firebaseapp.com/drive/classes/Resource$Files.html#watch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You want to retrieve the duration of the video on your Google Drive.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

If my understanding is correct, how about this sample script? In this modification, I used files.get and files.list methods of Drive API. From your question, I thought that the script that the endpoint is directly requests might be useful for your situation. So I proposed the following script.

### 1. Using files.get method

In this sample script, the duration is retrieved from a video file.

#### Sample script:

```
function sample1() {
  var fileId = "###"; // Please set the file ID of the video file.

  var fields = "mimeType,name,videoMediaMetadata"; // duration is included in "videoMediaMetadata"
  var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/" + fileId + "?fields=" + encodeURIComponent(fields) + "&access_token=" + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var obj = JSON.parse(res);
  Logger.log("filename: %s, duration: %s seconds", obj.name, obj.videoMediaMetadata.durationMillis / 1000);

  // DriveApp.getFiles() // This line is put for automatically detecting the scope (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly) for this script.
}
```

### 2. Using files.list method

In this sample script, the durations are retrieved from a folder including the video files.

#### Sample script:

```
function sample2() {
  var folderId = "###"; // Please set the folder ID including the video files.

  var q = "'" + folderId + "' in parents and trashed=false";
  var fields = "files(mimeType,name,videoMediaMetadata)"; // duration is included in "videoMediaMetadata"
  var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q=" + encodeURIComponent(q) + "&fields=" + encodeURIComponent(fields) + "&access_token=" + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var obj = JSON.parse(res);
  for (var i = 0; i < obj.files.length; i++) {
    Logger.log("filename: %s, duration: %s seconds", obj.files[i].name, obj.files[i].videoMediaMetadata.durationMillis / 1000);
  }

  // DriveApp.getFiles() // This line is put for automatically detecting the scope (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly) for this script.
}
```

### Note:

- These are simple sample scripts. So please modify them for your situation.
- I'm not sure about the format of your video files. So if above script cannot be used for your situation, I apologize.

### References:

- [Files of Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files)
- [Class UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

#### Updated: March 19, 2020

From January, 2020, the access token cannot be used with the query parameter like `access_token=###`. [Ref](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/application-development/upcoming-changes-to-the-google-drive-api-and-google-picker-api) So please use the access token to the request header instead of the query parameter. It's as follows.

```
var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {headers: {Authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}});
```

Comment: @Dave Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.