# Iterate Through Folders/Subfolders/Files in Google Drive and get video duration

Tags: google-apps-script

**My goal is to calculate the total length - in seconds - of all videos within all sub directories of a Google Drive folder.**

I have followed the Answer from here: [Iterate Through Folders/Subfolders/Files in Google Drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25145137/iterate-through-folders-subfolders-files-in-google-drive) to try and create a script that iterates through all directories within a folder and grabs the file count, plus file name and video duration if the file is a video.

I am currently using:

```
function testTraverse(){
  var originFolder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName('All Media').next(); 
  var totalCount = traverseFolder(originFolder,0);
  Logger.log('total files = '+totalCount);
}

 function getVideoDuration(folder,folderId, files) {  
  var q = "'" + folderId + "' in parents and trashed=false";
  var fields = "files(mimeType,name,videoMediaMetadata)"; 
  var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q=" + encodeURIComponent(q) + "&fields=" + encodeURIComponent(fields) + "&access_token=" + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {muteHttpExceptions: true});
  var obj = JSON.parse(res);  

   for (var i = 0; i < obj.files.length; i++) {
      sum += obj.files[i].videoMediaMetadata.durationMillis / 1000; 
   }
   Logger.log("Total duration: " + sum);    
 }

function traverseFolder(folder,total) {
  var name = folder.getName();
  var count = 0;
  var files = folder.getFiles();     
  var folderId = folder.getId();     


  while (files.hasNext()) {
    count++; 
    getVideoDuration(folderId, files);

  }

  var subs = folder.getFolders();
  while (subs.hasNext()) {
    total+=traverseFolder(subs.next(),count);
  }
  return total;
}
```

Running the above throws an error from the line: `for (var i = 0; i < obj.files.length; i++)`:

```
Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

Which is confusing, because I am in a directory with multiple files.

And the function I am way out of my depth with is the getVideoDuration, which I used from the sample script from the answer here: [How to get file (video) duration of google drive file programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55989742/how-to-get-file-video-duration-of-google-drive-file-programmatically).

My desired result is to calculate the total length - in seconds - of all videos within all sub directories.

Is there a simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Understanding

- You want to retrieve all files under the all sub folders in the specific folder.
- From retrieved all files, you want to retrieve only video files. And you want to retrieve the number of files, filenames and the total length of the video files.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

#### Modification points:

- I think that your error of `Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` is due to the following 2 reasons.

  1. About `getVideoDuration(folderId, files)` in `traverseFolder`, you send `folderId, files` as the arguments. But at the function of `getVideoDuration`, the script is `getVideoDuration(folder,folderId, files)`. By this, the folder ID is not used. And also, `files` is not used in `getVideoDuration`.
  2. From [this official document](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/application-development/upcoming-changes-to-the-google-drive-api-and-google-picker-api), the query parameter of `access_token` cannot be used now. So it is required to use the access token at the request header. I thought that I had modified my answers related to this. But I had forgot to modify to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55989742/how-to-get-file-video-duration-of-google-drive-file-programmatically). I apologize for this.
- `sum` is not declared. By this, an error occurs.
- When the files except for video are in the folder, an error occurs at `obj.files[i].videoMediaMetadata.durationMillis`.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
// Please run this function.
function testTraverse() {
  var originFolder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName('All Media').next(); 
  var res = traverseFolder(originFolder, {totalLength: 0, totalFiles: 0, filenames: []});
  Logger.log(res)
}

function getVideoDuration(folderId, o) {
  var q = "'" + folderId + "' in parents and trashed=false";
  var fields = "files(mimeType,name,videoMediaMetadata)"; 
  var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q=" + encodeURIComponent(q) + "&fields=" + encodeURIComponent(fields);
  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {muteHttpExceptions: true, headers: {authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}});
  var obj = JSON.parse(res);
  for (var i = 0; i < obj.files.length; i++) {
    var file = obj.files[i];
    if (file.hasOwnProperty("videoMediaMetadata")) {
      o.filenames.push(file.name);
      o.totalFiles++;
      o.totalLength += file.videoMediaMetadata.durationMillis / 1000;
    }
  }
 }

function traverseFolder(folder, obj) {
  var name = folder.getName();
  var count = 0;
  var files = folder.getFiles();
  var folderId = folder.getId();
  if (files.hasNext()) getVideoDuration(folderId, obj);
  var subs = folder.getFolders();
  while (subs.hasNext()) {
    traverseFolder(subs.next(), obj);
  }
  return obj;
}
```

- In this case, the result returns an object like `{totalLength: ##, totalFiles: ##, filenames: [###]}`. `totalLength`, `totalFiles` and `filenames` are the total length of video length, the total number of video files and the filenames of video files, respectively.

#### Note:

- Unfortunately, I'm not sure about the mimeTypes of your video files. So if the mimeTypes are found, I think that the process cost can be reduce a little. Because the files can be retrieved by the mimeTypes.
- I think that this modified script can be run with and without V8.

#### Reference:

- [fetch(url, params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params)